# how to fix this condition will always return false in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

anybody know why I'm getting " This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'typeof ChartType' and 'ChartType' have no overlap " when ever I tried to see if charTypeEnum is equal to ChartType.text

Chart-Design.ts

```
import { ChartType, ChartData, TextData } from 'src/app/mam-chart/models';

export class ChartDesignComponent implements OnInit {
  chartTypeEnum = ChartType;
}

  setupTypes() {
// I got error over here
    if (this.chartTypeEnum == ChartType.text)  { 
      this.cardJsonV2 = JSON.stringify(this.chartData);
    }
}
```

mam-model.ts

```
export enum ChartType {
    chart = 1,
    text,
    grid
}
```

Chart-Design.html

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput [ngModel]="chartData?.textData?.text" />
            </mat-form-field >
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `chartTypeEnum = ChartType` with `chartTypeEnum: ChartType`.

With `chartTypeEnum = ChartType` the type `ChartType` is (wrongfully?) assigned to the variable `chartTypeEnum` instead of defining the type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Typecasting

```
 if (String(this.chartTypeEnum) === ChartType.text))  {
```

Comment: Hi thank for the answer but now I'm getting " if (String(this.chartTypeEnum) == ChartType.text)) ".. anychance do you know why I'm getting this.

Comment: should be === if you are doing the check